# because it is not being besties with your principal

Tags: present-continuous

**Mom**: Hey, Alexa, look at this. You got a note from the principal. She says she is aware of your situation , and we can count on her for any help and support we need. This is pretty cool.

**Alexa**: Mom you have clearly lost touch with what "cool" means, **because it is not being besties with your principal.**

**Alexa's brother**: Oh, yes, principal Trugly is horrible. I got detention for a week just for skipping homeroom. No one can stand her. They call her ugly Trugly

**Mom**: That is awful! - We used to call her the same thing! Well, not your father! She loved your dad! He was such a suck-up!

TV Series: Alexa and Katie
Alexa & Katie is a dramedy about two teen best friends, one of whom has cancer.

What does the bold part mean?

Comment: Nothing is underlined in the question.

Comment: ***To be besties** [with someone]* is "mock childish / baby talk" meaning *to have someone as your **bestie / bezzie / best friend***. Alexa is telling her mother that it's "not cool" to be that close to the principal (school/college head).

Comment: "besties" is more teen or pre-teen talk in the US, not baby-talk or child-talk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that it is not "cool" to be best friends with the school principal.

Mom says "The principal will help you.  That is cool".

Alexa says "You have forgotten what 'cool' means. Being close to the principal is not 'cool'."  When Alexa says "It's not being besties...", "it" refers to "being cool". She needs the word "being" to form a noun clause. "being" is a gerund.

The overall structure is "*Main clause*, because *subordinate clause*". The main clause has a vocative "Mom", then the subject "you", the verb phrase "have clearly lost touch" (present perfect, with an adverb "clearly" and compound verb "lose touch"). The main clause has a prepostional phrase "with + noun phrase" and the noun phrase is a clause "what 'cool' means".

The subordinate clause is headed by the conjuction "because". There is a subject "it" (refering to "being cool"). The verb is "is not" and the complement is a gerund "being besties with your Principal"

But Alexa adds irony by exaggerating.

Comment: Does "it" refer to "cool"? Why did Alexa use "being"? Could she say "because it is not besties with your principal."?

Comment: @samsam No. You could say, "Being besties with your principal is not cool." or "Being cool is not the same as being besties with your principal.

Comment: Thanks @Jemes K. English is really an amazing and crazy language. You, helpers here,  also are making it the most amazing one.